# Clear PhoneGap Cache

Tags: cordova

When I deploy my PhoneGap application to my iPad, it doesn't show the most recent version.  I'm guessing this is because the WebView is caching stuff.  I can't figure out how to clear it.

So far I have..

- Rebooted
- Hard Rebooted
- Removed Application
- Cleared Safari Cache

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clean the project in Xcode, cmd+shift+k. Xcode caches html files heavily, in this case it's most likely the index.html file. Instill the clean project step in your mind as you need to do it every time you deploy to device.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the clean project suggestion above and it does not work.
You need to rebuild the app from the command line using cordova.

cordova build ios

This works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Phone gaps `localStore` may use this files (on real device)

```
find / -type f -name '*appdata.db'
find / -type f -name 'file__0'
find / -type f -name 'Databases.db'
find / -type f -name '*localstorage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I would edit the code in my html or js files.

If you add a line by Enter Key in the codes and save it.Then you run it,all the new codes are running on your app.

xcode cache is quite heavy.